# Googly Play Store won't open. I'm unable to get stated with my MM installation, please help

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-play-services

I have a OnePlus One. I installed CM 13 nightly, the relevant Slim GApps Nano, and Xposed v80 last evening. Ever since the setup screen, the pop-up saying "Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped working." has been harassing me. It goes away before I press the OK button.

Here are the things I've tried:-
- Clear Dalvik/Cache again
- Couldn't clear App Data because it's a fresh installation containing the latest versions.
- Manually installed Play Store and Services using APKs from APK Mirror.
- Restarted my device countless times.

Here is the crash log/bug report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.google.android.finsky.FinskyApp: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage(int, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4754)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:681)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(<Xposed>)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage(int, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1626)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageInstaller$Stub$Proxy.getMySessions(IPackageInstaller.java:385)
    at android.content.pm.PackageInstaller.getMySessions(PackageInstaller.java:415)
    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.v.<init>(SourceFile:77)
    at com.google.android.finsky.FinskyApp.onCreate(SourceFile:18023)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4751)
    ... 12 more
```

I have absolutely no idea what else I can do, except wait for Cyanogen OS 13. Please guide me towards a quick, and efficient solution. Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: What SDK version of Xposed did you install?

Comment: Did you flash Gapps for marshmallow?
The problem you r facing typically is encountered if you flash non compatible version of Gapps to the OS that is installed.